# How to prevent InitializeComponent code from constructing a member field / property

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, wpf-controls

Firstly I'm very new to WPF (coming from WinForms) and I'm facing quite a difficult problem. Sorry if it's rather lengthy, I've tried to give it structure and shorten it down.

**Environment (brief)**

I'm using a custom user control `CaptureControl` inside my `MainWindow`. This control has an encapsuled field / property of an `InputManager` object. This `InputManager` object is instantiated a single time in the global `App` class. It is later assigned to user control members (e.g. the `CaptureControl`).

**Problem**

My problem with this is that for some reason the `InitializeComponent()` call inside my `CaptureControl` constructs an instance of `InputManager` somewhere in *external code*. The `InputManager` registers event handlers to a static class during construction and **needs to be disposed** in order to unregister these handlers again. Sadly **whatever constructs an instance of the `InputManager` class does not dispose it properly again** or keeps it referenced at some place where I can't access it. The `_InputManager` field remains being null.

This is the problematic code:

```
public partial class CaptureControl : UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Gets or sets the Input Manager to be used</para>
    /// </summary>
    public InputManager InputManager
    {
        get => _InputManager;
        set
        {
            _InputManager = value;
            lstTriggeredKeys.DataContext = _InputManager;
        }
    }
    private InputManager _InputManager;

    public CaptureControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // This calls external code which constructs an instance of InputManager
    }
}
```

This invokes the constructor of my `InputManager` class:

```
public class InputManager : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Constructs the input helper</para>
    /// <para>Registers static keyboard events</para>
    /// </summary>
    public InputManager()
    {
        Interceptor.OnKeyInput += Interceptor_OnKeyInput;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Releases static keyboard events</para>
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Interceptor.OnKeyInput -= Interceptor_OnKeyInput;
    }

    private void Interceptor_OnKeyInput(KeyInput input)
    { ... }
}
```

Which results in two problems:

1. There is an event handler unnecessarily being invoked on an anonymous object
2. The dependent clean-up logic on the static class is not fired if the event handler count is higher than 0

**Question**

I have difficulties understanding why the `InitializeComponent()` call would construct an instance of `InputManager` in the first place.

> How can this be prevented? How can I prevent the external code behind
>   `InitializeComponent()` to construct an instance of
>   `InputManager` for whatever reason?

**Call Stack**

The **external code** call stack behind `InitializeComponent()` is huge and ends with an invisible native to managed transition. The last visible record before reaching the `InputManager` constructor is:

```
> InputData.dll!InputData.InputManager.InputManager() Line 40   C#
> [Native to Managed Transition]
> [Managed to Native Transition]
> mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(bool publicOnly, bool skipCheckThis, bool fillCache = true, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)
> ...
> InputH.exe!InputH.CaptureControl.InitializeComponent() Line 1 C#
> ...
```

**Environment (detailed)**

The `App` class which inherits the `System.Windows.Application` class and constructs the `InputManager` object. The object is assigned to one or more user controls later on:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    // Single instance / global / shared object
    public InputManager InputManager { get; private set; } = new InputManager();

    // Disposing of the object
    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnExit(e);
        InputManager.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The global `InputManger` instance is assigned to the user control in the Constructor of my `MainWindow`. It also assigns the shared single instance `InputManager` object to it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        captureControl.InputManager = ((App)Application.Current).InputManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: This description seems a bit muddled.  Is InputHelper the same as InputManager?

Comment: @AQuirky Whoops, that happens if you rename classes while writing a question. Sorry, it's the same. Fixed.

Comment: There has to be a place where the inputmanager is initialized. Have you looked at your XAML? (I suspect that the InitializeComponent call also takes care of XAML parsing) If you have an instance that you need for your app, you could also put it in your App's Resource Dictionary for easy reference, see `StaticBinding`. That would mean less CodeBehind and you can be explicit about the controls using it.

Comment: I would suggest you to simply text search your whole project for "InputManager". There is somewhere a ctor call - the Framework doesn't instantiate user code objects just because it is so funny.